# How to email pictures in vb?

Tags: vb.net, email

I have a folder(open.SelectedPath) full of images and want to email them the code below doesn't work for some reason. The code below that works though.

```
For Each File In open.SelectedPath
 attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(File)
 mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
```

The code that does work:

```
  attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("ImageLocation")
     mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What are the objects in `open.SelectedPath`? Are they `FileInfo`s? You might need `File.FullName` or similar

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time I figured it out after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
 For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(open.SelectedPath)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
                Next
                For Each item In ListBox1.Items
                    attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(item)
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
                Next
```